# Is there a possibility to control multiple ( nested #include ) inclusions of .MQH header file in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

For MQL4, will it include the `.MQH` header files multiple times, if say one header file makes use of the header files we already included?

If yes, how to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot.

Like in the previous question - `CElem` calls `CObject` that calls `CStdLibErr.mqh`. `CArrayObj` also calls `CArray` that includes `CObject` that has a reference to `CStdLibErr.mqh`, so `CObject` is called twice.

If you do not want to call ( `#include` ) the same `.MQH` twice - maybe need to create its copy or inherit.

Comment: Does it matter from performance or other perspectives for including it multiple times?

Comment: Difficult question about performance... when compiling, EX4 file is created that includes your main file and all supplementary files. as far as i remember, there was an article at mql5.com where the author compared speeds of using moving averages called in different ways. single file turned out to work faster then a file with links to other files. cannot tell if the speed increase was significant.

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way as in C/C++.

```
#ifndef MY_UNIQUE_HEADER_ID_H
#define MY_UNIQUE_HEADER_ID_H

<header file content goes here>

#endif
```

You can edit standard header files and add this shim, if you want. There's no harm in doing so and it might even slightly improve up your compilation time.